# Doesn't documentation seem "wiki-ish?"

Tags: discussion, documentation

I get the point of the documentation in SE. But it seems like a gamified version of a wiki site. Are there even any major differences between documentation and a wiki-style documentation?

Comment: yeah, the wiki part.

Comment: it's wiki-ish. so what? what's your point? are wikis bad?

Comment: @uoɥʇʎPʎzɐɹC No, it just seems redundant.

Comment: One difference: in Docs, there's no talk page on which to coordinate with other editors.  Instead, everyone just adds stuff in the hope someone else will organize it later.

Comment: @tox123 imagine the docs without wiki editing. a whole load of duplicate examples and information

Comment: Have you used wikimedia before?  Aside from the fact that users can add and edit content, it's pretty much completely different.  There's no approval process on wiki.  The organization is completely different, as is the syntax.  There's no voting.  The formatting is different.  In fact, I'd be hard pressed to find many similarities at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everyone can edit a wiki-style documentation, thus keeping it up-to-date as the documented software is patched over time.

That's why Documentation is wiki-ish.

> it seems like a gamified version of a wiki site

This thing called "reputation" is why >1% of all Stack Overflow users<sup>1</sup> signed up in the first place. Why not apply such a motivating/satisfying feature to an extension of the site?

<sup>1 - This includes me.</sup>